# Pattern matching with regular expression Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a sentence and want to check if a pattern exist or not.
I am looking for pattern '...switch from...to...' is such a pattern exist return true otherwise false. 
How can I write a regular expression for it in python?

Comment: [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search)`('switch.*from.*to', string)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re.match('switch.*from.*to', txt)`